# I can connect to webservice in .NET but I always get anyType {Id=null} Android

Tags: android, .net, service, web

I have an app that connects to a webservice in `.NET`. The connection is ok. I don't get any error or exception, but always get the same: `anyType {Id=null}`.

The method gets 2 parameters `usuario` and `password`, but no matter what I send I always get the same.

Here is my code:

```
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "usuarioLogeadoSOAP_XML";
     private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://xxxx/webdav/testapp/usuarioLogeadoSOAP_XML";
     private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://xxxx/webdav/testapp";
     private static final String URL = "http://xxxx/testapp/Service.asmx";


try{
       result=soap(METHOD_NAME, SOAP_ACTION, NAMESPACE, URL);
 } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }

     public SoapObject soap(String METHOD_NAME, String SOAP_ACTION, String NAMESPACE, String URL) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException 
     {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("usuario", "roman");
        request.addProperty("password", "hernandez");
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);  
        httpTransport.debug = true; 
        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapObject result=(SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
        return result;
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i found the solution, whit .NET is necessary to add this line

```
envelope.dotNet=true;
```

and voila, now is working.